# Making QR Code reader start again when stopped swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, qr-code

I have a QR code reader that when finding a QR code is opening up my detailViewController in a modal.  On my detailViewController you are able to dismiss the modal, for instance if it is not the right QR code you wanted to scan. The problem is that in my code the QR code reader is set to stop, when the QR code is found and when you dismiss the modal, it does not start up again? How can I make it start up again?

Here you have my code from the QR code viewcontroller, just the part that does something to the rest of my app when finding a QR code and at the bottom stopping the QR reader:

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            // messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue

            messageLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 46/255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 113/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            messageLabel.text = "QR code found!"
            passData = metadataObj.stringValue as String

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender: self.passData)
            }

            self.captureSession!.stopRunning() // This is the part stopping it
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is stopping because you are stopping the `captureSession`

```
self.captureSession!.stopRunning() // This is the part stopping it
```

After dismissing your ViewController you have to check whether your `self.captureSession` is nil or not, if it is nil then you have to create a new capture session and if it is not nil then you have to start that session again.Like this

```
self.captureSession!.startRunning()
```

So in `viewDidLoad` initialize your captureSession and in `viewWillAppear` start your session.As on Dismissing the ViewController, viewDidLoad will not called.

Comment: should I put the if statement incl. that code at the top of viewDidLoad?

Comment: I have added this code, between the viewDidLoad and the didRecieveMemoryWarning: `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if captureSession == nil {
            captureSession!.startRunning()
        }
    }` but without any luck. It still doesn't start again when dismissing.

Comment: if captureSession != nil { captureSession!.startRunning() }